# Fuzzy compare two strings and add 1 or 0 to df if ratio is bigger than x, 8 millon rows dataset

Tags: python

I hade a df of about 8M rows, I would like to each string value in `Data["title"]` to a list of string and see if the ratio is bigger than 80 in any case. If it is, return `1` else return `0`

The way I am doing it right now:

```
won = []
for title in tqdm(Data["title"]):
    ratio = []
    for wonTitle in titles["title"]:
        ratio.append(fuzz.ratio(title, wonTitle))
    tmp = [i >= 80 for i in ratio]
    if True in tmp:
        won.append(1)
    else:
        won.append(0)
```

Problem with this is that tqdm estimates it to take about 300 hours...

## Edit:

This solution got it down to about 80 hours.

```
def fuzzyCompare(title):
    return int(any(1 for wonTitle in titles["title"] if fuzz.ratio(title.lower(), wonTitle.lower()) >= 80))
Data["won"] = Data['title'].swifter.apply(fuzzyCompare)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @mkrieger1 To speed it up and not take 300 hours. There must be a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you profile it? Where is the time spent?

Comment: The inner content of the loop could be written as `won.append( any(1 for wonTitle in titles["title"] if fuzz.ratio(title, wonTitle) >= 80) )` Maybe this will speed things up a little bit.

Comment: @mkrieger1 `0%|                                                                       | 5740/7471485 [08:08<220:44:48,  9.39it/s]`

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thanks, removed about 100 hours...

Comment: @Jesper.Lindberg This should be good case for [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html) I think.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes, been thinking about it as well. Also the fuzzy package can be sped up by installing `python-Levenshtein`, however i run into an issue with the install. https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/issues/45 I will give multiprocessing a go I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fuzzyCompare(title):
    return int(any(1 for wonTitle in titles["title"] if fuzz.ratio(title.lower(), wonTitle.lower()) >= 80))

pandarallel.initialize(progress_bar = True)
Data["won"] = Data["title"].parallel_apply(fuzzyCompare)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I see is that the problem you have is of high time complexity. In order to reduce is what you can do is:

1. As each loop is independent you can run them parallelly. (https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/parallel-processing-python/ this is an excellent resource on threading)
2. you break out of the loop as soon as you cross your threshold.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!
I tried this solution but when processing the data I did not managed to get a progress bar working (which is a must so I know about how long it will take). Nor did I get more than 5% utilization on any of my cores...?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some basic `multiprocessing` skeleton, you need to adapt it to your needs (put `tqdm` ...):

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import time
import random

the_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
queue_out = multiprocessing.Queue()

won_titles = ['some title 1', 'some title 2', 'some title 3']
data = ['my data 1', 'my data 2', 'my data 3']

def worker_main(queue, queue_out):
    print(os.getpid(),"working")

    def work(item):
        # return int( any(1 for wonTitle in won_titles if fuzz.ratio(item.lower(), wonTitle.lower()) >= 80) )  # also consider to lowercase all items before running

        # here i just return some random value
        return random.choice([0, 1])

    while True:
        item = queue.get(True)  # wait for job
        queue_out.put( (item, work(item)) )

the_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3, worker_main, (the_queue, queue_out)) # 3 processes

for d in data: # here you could put tqdm
    the_queue.put(d)

# wait some time for jobs to finish
time.sleep(5)

# get results
out_dict = {}
while not queue_out.empty():
    d, result = queue_out.get_nowait()
    out_dict[d] = result

#print(out_dict) # for example {'my data 1': 0, 'my data 3': 1, 'my data 2': 0}

final_result = [out_dict[d] for d in data]   # maybe the out_dict is enough for you already, here i convert it to list
print(final_result) # [0, 0, 1]
```